# iOS Not Recognizing Each Touch

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, touch

I am trying to have a sprite appear on screen when the user taps the screen. I am using the default SpriteKit game provided by Xcode, and below is the method I'm using for detecting when the user taps the screen. The issue I'm having is that often I tap the screen but a sprite does not appear as it should. Any ideas why this may be happening?

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
   /* Called when a touch begins */

    for touch in touches {

        let sprite = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed:"mySprite")

        sprite.xScale = 0.3
        sprite.yScale = 0.3

        let dotX = (drand48() * Double (view!.scene!.frame.size.width))
        let dotY = (drand48() * Double (view!.scene!.frame.size.height))

        print (dotX)
        print (dotY)

        sprite.position.x = CGFloat (dotX)
        sprite.position.y = CGFloat (dotY)

        self.addChild(sprite)

    }
}
```

Comment: what does your dotX and dotY say?  Your sprites could just be on the edges of your screen

Comment: @Knight0fDragon, here's a few taps' worth of logs. The last one is one where the sprite didn't show up (I apologize that the formatting is terrible):

dotX: 405.979928330522
dotY: 645.492763707975
location of tap: (317.913024902344, 42.4347839355469)

dotX: 361.816163579129
dotY: 342.976077923746
location of tap: (724.869567871094, 764.521728515625)

dotX: 326.341398847366
dotY: 680.777036715288
location of tap: (300.869567871094, 762.434814453125)

dotX: 15.9568377941287
dotY: 448.581289203665
location of tap: (723.130432128906, 4.86959838867188)

Comment: No idea what those numbers mean, but if your y is 4, then it sounds like my theory is correct and your scene is outside of your view

Comment: They're the coordinates of the sprite. the location of taps are meant to show the bounds of the screen. Do you know how I could restrict the sprites to only show up within the bounds of the screen?

Comment: oh I get it, so yes x@15 might not be on screen, what is your scalemode

Comment: ok, chances are your default scene is a square, so with aspect fill, your sides get chopped off

Comment: I changed it to .ResizeFill and that corrected the issue. Thanks for your help!

Comment: that may not be an answer to your problem,  you need to figure out how you want to handle it across different devices

Comment: I have tested it on several simulated devices and it is performing as desired

Comment: my point being the game is may be different experience across devices

Comment: I see. I will look into how it should be handled across different devices. Thank you for pointing me in the correct direction, I would never have thought to check the scale mode